# Why do packages installed with `pip install -e .` not need __init__.py?

Tags: python, python-packaging

I recently discovered that a package which was installed with

```
$ pip install -e .
```

did not have an `__init__.py` file in a subpackage. Still, I could import it without problems. When I installed the same with

```
$ pip install .
```

I could not import the subpackage. Why?

(In case it matters: I use Python 3.6)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Folders with no `__init__.py` may be treated as part of an [implicit namespace package](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/). Unless you know what a namespace package is and specifically want one, you should still include `__init__.py` in your packages, but that's what's going on here.

With `pip install -e .`, `pip` installs a thing that tells Python to look directly in your original source folder for the package contents. When Python looks in your source folder, it finds the no-`__init__.py` folders.

With `pip install .`, `pip` only installs what `setup.py` says to install, and your `setup.py` does not say to install the no-`__init__.py` folders. Python looks in the installed version of the package, not your original source folder, and it does not find the no-`__init__.py` folders.